# How can I change the path name of a folder when it remains unchanged after renaming?

Tags: windows-10, path, rename

I am currently using a Windows 10 computer. The situation is like this: I copied and pasted a folder called "abc" in the same folder where it existed. After pasting, the folder name of the pasted folder was, for some reason, the same as the copied folder, which was also "abc", and that should not be possible to start with. When I tried to rename the pasted folder to "abcd", it succeeded. The name was changed. However, when I clicked into "abcd", and then clicked on the path bar, it showed the folder name was actually "abc - Copied". What is happening and what can I do to change the folder path name?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a screenshot to better explain your question

Answer (score 0):

Go inside the folder that is misnamed, show hidden files, and delete any desktop.ini files.

Folders can have labels that are different from their folder names. These labels will show in File Explorer when you view the folder. This value will be stored in the desktop.ini file, and deleting this will remove the label and any other customizations that may be hanging on to the folder.

Another way is to right-click on the folder in question, select Properties, and remove name of the folder from the top field in this dialog.